# Git hook to preserve windows file permissions

Tags: python, windows, git, githooks, windows-security

I have a local git repository which is upstream from another local git repository. When I pull from the upstream repository to the downstream one, I want the Windows file permissions on a particular file to be preserved after the update. I attempted using the following solution: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/hooks/setgitperms.perl#L78

But I believe it is based on a UNIX security model and does not preserve my permissions. How can I accomplish this? I was considering using a python script with the win32security module (since I'm not familiar with perl), but have been unable to find suitable documentation for it. I have very little experience with Windows security beyond manually setting permissions.

Comment: What is your primary question? If it is just "How can I accomplish this?" then that is too broad since there are countless ways.

Comment: @PatrickParker Actually I think this is just fine. "How can I do this?" type questions are not *inherently* too broad, only when they're like "How do I program a Facebook clone?". This question has a clear and *specific* problem.

Comment: Possibly. Either way the question needs to be clarified to show more clearly what is the primary thing being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your git config to ignore file permissions differences with

```
git config --global core.fileMode false
```

Worth giving it a try I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being quite simple. I just had to set post-checkout and -merge hooks that ran a python script to set up the file permissions. I gleaned enough about win32security from [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/add-security-to-a-file.html) to work with it and made use of os.getcwd() (which is set to the git repo root while the hook is running) to locate the correct file.